# Tracking down speckled/marbled upholstery fabric

Tags: sewing, fabric

I'm working on a project that requires some upholstery work and I cant seem to track down the fabric I'd like. I'm looking for [this pattern](https://www.westelm.com/products/mathias-mid-century-wood-frame-loveseat-h2314/) or something near it

[image]

The style shown on the website isn't sold anymore, but when it was they called it **Nordic Weave, Indigo** and that's about all the information I have on it. I've searched for quite a while to find it or something similar and I can't find anything.

Does anyone have a clue of where I might find this fabric?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking after a product recommendation, it is open-ended, opinion-based, and has nothing to do with a creative process.

Answer (score 1):

There are some similar fabrics at [lavivahome.com](https://www.lavivahome.com/shop/fabrics-wallpapers/djellaba-collection-fabric/). They call it *cotton stria* and *wool bouclè*.

[image]